# My responsive email is not supported in outlook

Tags: email, html-email, responsive-emails

I am trying to making responsive html email, Which Email Will be supported to all email client. My coding is not properly supported in Outlook.
I have no lots of knowledge of this work. But I have lots interest for this. For this I need helps of expert.
Please check my bellow Email Coding from below link: 
http://htmlchecking.blogspot.com/2018/05/2-3-column.html

Please help me, How to solve this problem???

Comment: Outlook 2007-2016 does not support media queries.

Comment: Just as gwally said Outlook doesnt support media queries and you need to put your styles inline.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's only support for basic HTML in *Outlook*.
Many *tags* and *css rules* are not supported by the client. Something you can try to do is
create an email (`Outlook -> Insert -> Choose your file`) then click 'Insert as Text'.

More info: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-insert-html-source-code-outlook-emails-maurizio-la-cava and https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML-based emails. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12))
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200%28v%3Doffice.12%29)

Word supports a subset of the standard HTML 4.01 specification and of the Internet Explorer 6.0 HTML specification. Word also supports a subset of the standard Cascading Stylesheet Specification, Level 1. Word uses HTML elements that support a subset of the Word cascading style sheets properties.